# javafx2: css documentation

Tags: javafx-2

Reading blogs and articles on using css in javafx, I see class selectors such as

```
.table-row-cell:empty {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-base;
}

.table-row-cell:empty .table-cell {
    -fx-border-width: 0px;
}
```

being used, and indeed they work in my own code. However I can't find anywhere where these are documented - it seems like the official documentation has no mention of them:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this official tutorial [Skinning JavaFX Applications with CSS](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) section **Default Style Sheet**.

> The default style sheet for JavaFX applications is caspian.css, which
>   is found in the JavaFX runtime JAR file, jfxrt.jar. This style sheet
>   defines styles for the root node and the UI controls. ...

You can find out those selectors in mentioned CSS file.